# Show a UILabel for * seconds; other ways than with NSTimer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Are there any other way of displaying an object/button/whatever,for example 3 seconds than with an NSTimer?
Could I use an animation to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, though it uses a timer internally.

```
[theLabel performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

You cannot use `-setHidden:` with this method because `1` is not an object, but you can use `NSInvocation`.

```
NSInvocation* invoc = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[theLabel methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setHidden:)]];
[invoc setTarget:theLabel];
[invoc setSelector:@selector(setHidden:)];
BOOL yes = YES;
[invoc setArgument:&yes atIndex:2];
[invoc performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

Comment: Thanks.
I think I'm going to go with the animation, tough ;)

Comment: Or you can just add a category to UILabel overloading setHidden: that accept an object, say NSNumber.

- (void)setHidden:(NSNumber *)hide
{
  [super setHidden:[hide boolValue];
}

Then use the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.

Marco

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
[UIVIew beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:3];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1]; //or lower than 0.1
button.hidden = YES;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Marco

Comment: Typo in first bit:
UIVIew (big I should be small)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an UIImageView named myImageView: In your .h. file

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

In the .m file create a method to hide the object:

```
-(void)hideMyImageView {
    myImageView.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

Then when you want to hide the Object use this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideMyImageView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

To redisplay the object use this:

```
myImageView.hidden = FALSE;
```